# Open outlook email search from Java/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, outlook

Recently, I saw a form on SharePoint where user can select/search emails from a widget. It seemed to me that the emails were not locally stored and that SharePoint is somehow getting the emails from Outlook or an email server.

My question here would be that whether something like this is possible in Java/Javascript or not? So that I do not store emails locally and the search widget may bring the emails from an email server.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would have the page make an AJAX call to the web server, which would then make a call to the mail server (MS Exchange).

Comment: Is it _possible_? Most likely. I imagine it's just passing a simple filter and Outlook is returning whatever matches it. Was that your question?

Comment: Yes, we can refer the git link https://github.com/rjohnsondev/java-libpst